# ¿Consultas con horas en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, tsql

Tengo una pregunta sobre cómo puedo hacer consultas en SQL Server con campos de horas.

Tengo una columna llamada `hora_inicio_prestamo` y otra `hora_fin_prestamo`, los dos de tipo `time(0)`, también tengo una columna denominada `Estado_prestamo` lo que necesito es separar las horas que hay entre esas horas y decir si están en préstamo.

Ejemplo:

```
________________________________________________________________
|Hora_inicio_prestamo   |Hora_fin_prestamo | Estado_prestamo  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|7:00                   |  11:00             | EN PRESTAMO    |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

(Se podría realizar unos campos temporales así)

```
Hora  |   Estado
7:00 ---> EN PRESTAMO
8:00 ---> EN PRESTAMO
9:00 ---> EN PRESTAMO
10:00 ---> EN PRESTAMO
11:00 ---> EN PRESTAMO
12:00 ---> LIBRE
13:00 ---> LIBRE
```

He intentado crear campos dinámicos con el `CAST`, de esta manera:

```
SELECT Id_prestamo_laboratorio
    ,CAST('' AS TIME(0)) AS Siete
    ,CAST('' AS TIME(0)) AS Ocho
    ,CAST('' AS TIME(0)) AS Nueve
FROM PrestamoLaboratorios
```

Comment: saludos JDiego9708, ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: He intentado crear campos dinámicos con el cast, de esta manera:
`select Id_prestamo_laboratorio, CAST('' as time(0)) AS Siete, CAST('' as time(0)) AS Ocho, CAST('' as time(0)) AS Nueve
from PrestamoLaboratorios`

Comment: El apoyo que requieres ¿en que es? Como sacar el listado si esta o no en préstamo o libre, que en base a rango de hora si esta libre??? Claro que deberas proporcionar (completar planteamiento) según veas o se te sugiera agreges más información.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parte de este código

```
create table #Prestamos (HoraInicio time, HoraFin time, Estado Varchar(11))
insert into #Prestamos (HoraInicio, HoraFin) values ('7:00', '11:00')

declare @Contador tinyint = 24,
    @HoraInicio time = '00:00:00.0000000',
    @HoraFin time = '23:00:00.0000000'

while @Contador > 0
begin
    insert into #Prestamos (HoraInicio, HoraFin, Estado)
select  top 1
        @HoraInicio,
        @HoraFin,
        case
            when HoraInicio <= @HoraInicio  and HoraFin >= @HoraInicio
             then 'En préstamo'
          else 'Libre'
        end as Estado
from #Prestamos 

set @HoraInicio = dateadd(hour, 1, @HoraInicio)
set @Contador -= 1
select @Contador, @HoraInicio, @HoraFin

end

select  HoraInicio, 
    HoraFin, 
    Estado
from #Prestamos
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto solo es un complemento a la respuesta de Elena López, la cual me parece excelente, solo había que corregir un par de cosas en su código:

- La hora fin siempre quedaba como `23:00:00`, se ajustó con `SET @HoraFin = dateadd(hour, 1, @HoraInicio)`
- Dentro del `WHEN` se corrige la condición `AND HoraFin > @HoraInicio`, anteriormente tenía `>=`, lo cual ocasionaba que el horario se extendiera una hora más.

<kbd>[Demostración de la solución.](http://rextester.com/XDDSQ43319)</kbd>

Resultados:

```
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| HoraInicio | HoraFin  | Estado   |             |
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 1          | 07:00:00 | 13:00:00 | En préstamo |
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 2          | 08:00:00 | 09:00:00 | En préstamo |
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 3          | 09:00:00 | 10:00:00 | En préstamo |
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 4          | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 | En préstamo |
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 5          | 11:00:00 | 12:00:00 | Libre       |
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 6          | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | Libre       |
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 7          | 13:00:00 | 14:00:00 | Libre       |
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 8          | 14:00:00 | 15:00:00 | Libre       |
+------------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, tienes entera razón